# Calling infinite loop code multiple times on alarm

Tags: c, linux, unix, infinite-loop

I'm currently using an alarm signal `SIGALRM` to exit from an infinite loop.

My code is structured as follows

```
main_loop() {
    set_alarm();
    while(1)
        counter++;
}
```

The logic is
 - Set an alarm
 - Enter while loop
 - Read counter when we get `SIGALRM`

The code that runs upon `SIGALRM` is given below:

```
VERBOSE("Cycles :%u\n", counter);
iteration_index++;
if(iteration_index == iterations)
    exit(0);
counter = 0;
main_loop();
```

I would now like to now give the user an option to specify the number of times (`iterations`) the alarm should go off. In short, modify the above logic into:
 - Set an alarm
 - Enter while loop
 - Read counter when we get `SIGALRM`
 - Increment `iteration_index`
 -`If iteration_index < iterations`: call `main_loop`
 - Else exit

I implemented the above logic and found that it segfaults after a few thousand iterations. I believe that the reason for this is that:
When the alarm triggers and it makes a new call to `main_loop`, the original `main_loop` frame still exists. This keeps repeatedly happening until it runs out of space and throws a segfault.

I've tried coming up with some design that does what I want, but I'm unable to visualize code-flow after the signal is triggered.
What is the right way to implement what I've described?

Comment: Where is the code that runs when you receive the alarm?

Comment: What you tried..?? can you show us your code.

Comment: what do you mean by 'specifying the number of times (iterations) the alarm should go off'?? and what is the time you want to allocate to the alarm??

Comment: By using the iterations variable, I'm basically trying to compute an average. Therefore, if the number of iterations is 3, then run main_loop, get interrupted by the signal, increment iteration_index, run main_loop again, ..., for a total 3 times.  
I'm currently testing out the code with varying times - roughly between 1e7 and 1e9 nanoseconds.

Comment: Okay. now I understood.Your are still getting segfaults.??

Comment: Yes..I think this is because of the reason mentioned above. When I call `main_loop` from the alarm handler code, the original `main_loop` still exists..and these frames never get free'd. Thus eventually, I run out of memory.

Comment: Will using `GetAsynchKeyState()` work for getting user input?

Comment: The problem is not getting the user input..I already have that implemented using getopt_long. The problem is as follows: Assume the user wants 10iterations..so I first trigger `main_loop` from `main`..upon `SIGALRM`, I see that I have more iterations to perform, so I start `main_loop` from this function..HOWEVER, the original frame containing `main_loop` that was executing before the `SIGALRM` still exists..by now, another `SIGALRM` is issued and I create yet another frame that is executing `main_loop`..since the frames are never being free'd, I quickly run out of memory

Comment: It sounds as if you need to set some flags, or use thread locks to control access to a protected token.  If an alarm is currently running for a period of time, do not allow any other process to access that resource.  When the alarm is ready to leave, increment the iterator, set the token to _available_, then allow another thread to launch if one is queued up.

Comment: @ryyker: I wouldn't recommend adding threads to this program (`SIGALRM` does not use threads).

Answer (score 0):

Regrading the modifications you listed:

```
- Set an alarm
- Enter while loop
- Read counter when we get SIGALRM
- Increment iteration_index
- If iteration_index < iterations: call main_loop
- Else exit
```

You could provide a series of keystrokes (say `<ctrl> - 1`  to allow the user to specify a number of times (just once).  This example runs (with delays to allow some time for `GetAsyncKeys()`.   Until the user presses `<ctrl> 1`, the loop will run forever.   When `<ctrl> 1` is pressed, program prompts them with how many time to let the alarm sound, then programs runs that many iterations, then quits..

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>

void set_alarm(void);

int main(void) {
int iterations=-1, counter=0;
    while (iterations != counter) 
    {
        if(iterations == -1)//code will run forever if iteration is not set by user
        {

            set_alarm(); 
            counter++;
            if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_CONTROL)<0) 
            {

                if (GetAsyncKeyState('1')<0) 
                {
                    printf("Enter how many time alarm should activate:\n");
                    scanf("%d", &iterations);
                    counter = 0;
                    Sleep(10);
                }
            }
        }
        else//this block will monitor alarm count, program quits when limit reached.
        {
            if(counter < iterations)
            {
                set_alarm();
                counter++;
            }

        }
        Sleep(10);//changed here for my test, you might need to change again
    }

    return 0;
}

void set_alarm(void)
{
    //do something; 
}
```

Comment: This is a Windows solution, but the question is probably not Windows because it makes a reference to `SIGALRM` which is POSIX.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are right.  When the handler for `SIGALRM` runs, the `main_loop()` function is still running.  Both functions will in fact be running on the same thread.  If you never exit from the `SIGALRM` handler, then the next handler will go on top, and this will keep happening until you run out of stack and crash.

To fix this, simply return from the signal handler.

```
// Make sure that both of these are volatile
volatile int iteration_index;
volatile int counter;

void catch_sigalrm(int signo)
{
    // Note: this is not safe, so I commented it out
    // VERBOSE("Cycles :%u\n", counter);
    iteration_index++;
    if(iteration_index == iterations)
        exit(0);
    counter = 0;
    set_alarm();
}

void main_loop(void)
{
    set_alarm();
    while (1)
        __sync_fetch_and_add(&counter, 1);
}
```

I think this will work.  It should use `ldrex` and `strex` for incrementing `counter`.

The problem with using `counter++` is that it can be interrupted: `counter++` is actually something like this:

```
int old_value = counter; // memory access
int new_value = old_value + 1;
counter = new_value; // memory access
```

As you can see, if the alarm goes off in the middle of `counter++` the results will get wiped out.  That is why you need to use `__sync_fetch_and_add()` instead.

### The `volatile` specifier is MANDATORY

Here's the main loop with a normal counter variable.  I've removed the call to `set_alarm()` because we're not concerned about it right now.

```
// This is wrong
int counter;
void main_loop()
{
    while (1)
        counter++;
}
```

Here's the assembly:

```
_main_loop:
    b _main_loop

    .comm _counter, 4, 2
```

Wait a second!  It doesn't increment anything, it's just an infinite loop!

That's right.  The compiler detected that `counter` can not possibly be read anywhere, and so optimized the increment right out of existence.  You **MUST** use `volatile`.  The `volatile` keyword instructs the compiler that `counter` may be read or written by *something else* that is not a thread (actually, it instructs the compiler to be strict about loads and stores, but that's the technical version).  (For working with threads, `volatile` is almost never useful, you have to use atomics which are different.)

Here's the version with `volatile`:

```
// This is ALSO wrong
volatile int counter;
void main_loop(void)
{
    while (1) counter++;
}
```

And the assembly:

```
_main_loop:
    ; load address of counter into r0
    ...

loop:
    ; increment counter
    ldr  r1, [r0]
    adds r1, #1
    str  r1, [r0]

    b loop
```

As you can see, this can be interrupted in the middle.  This is why you have to use `__sync_fetch_and_add()`: it detects when `counter++` was interrupted and it restarts the operation from the beginning.

Here is the correct version:

```
// MUST be volatile
volatile int counter;
void main_loop(void)
{
    while (1)
        __sync_fetch_and_add(&counter, 1);
}
```

### More notes

- You can't call `printf()` in a signal handler.
- In fact, try to avoid doing *anything* in a signal handler.
- At most, set a flag, write a byte to a pipe, or something like that.

Comment: @user1761555: What processor are you using?  Is `counter` marked `volatile`?  Answer both questions.

Comment: @user1761555: Remember that you can't call `printf()` from inside a signal handler.

Comment: Processor : ARMv7 Processor rev 2 (v7l)

counter is declared as follows: `register unsigned int counter asm("r6");`

Comment: @user1761555: That explains things.  The `counter++` instruction can be interrupted on ARM processors.  I'll expand the answer.

Comment: I was unaware that single-cycle instructions could be interrupted! Having said that, I realize that counter++ translates to 3 instructions without using optimization flags..but I also tried the same with inline assembly `while(1) { asm("add r6, r6, #1"); }`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/40399/discussion-between-user1761555-and-dietrich-epp)